# django Error during template rendering

Tags: python, django

I am trying to pass values of multiple checkbox from a html template to views.py and then show those values in response. I created a forms.py in my application and defined a class. i then passed the value to pack method of views.py.

template:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'pack' %}">
    <div id="row-1">
        <button name="pack" id="pack">Pack</button>
    </div>
    <div id="row-2">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th><input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this, 'no')"></th>
                    <th>Order Id</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="no" value="10000001">10000001</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="no" value="10000002">10000002</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggle(source, text) {
        checkboxes = document.getElementsByName(text);
        for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
            checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
            }
        }
</script>
```

My views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from test1 import forms

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def pack(request):
    oid_list = []
    form = PackOrders(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        for item in form.cleaned_data['no']:
            oid_list.append(item)
    return HttpResponse(oid_list)
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms

class PackOrders(forms.Form):
    order_items = forms.CharField()
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns
from django.conf.urls import url
from test1 import views

urlpatterns = patterns('', 
                    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
                    url(r'^index.html', views.index, name='index1'),
                    url(r'^test/', 'views.pack', name='pack'),)
```

what is wrong with the code?

EDIT: It is throwing `Error during template rendering`

Traceback points to `<form method="POST" action="{% url 'pack' %}">`

```
Traceback:
File "/home/manish/syserp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/manish/syserp/chkbx/test1/views.py" in index
  7.    return render(request, 'index.html')
File "/home/manish/syserp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render
  67.             template_name, context, request=request, using=using)
File "/home/manish/syserp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  99.         return template.render(context, request)
File "/home/manish/syserp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  74.         return self.template.render(context)
File "/home/manish/syserp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  209.                     return self._render(context)
File "/home/manish/syserp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  201.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/manish/syserp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  903.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/manish/syserp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "/home/manish/syserp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  493.             url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
File "/home/manish/syserp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  579.     return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))
File "/home/manish/syserp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  433.             self._populate()
File "/home/manish/syserp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _populate
  308.                     for name in pattern.reverse_dict:
File "/home/manish/syserp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse_dict
  338.             self._populate()
File "/home/manish/syserp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _populate
  326.                 lookups.appendlist(pattern.callback, (bits, p_pattern, pattern.default_args))
File "/home/manish/syserp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in callback
  247.         self._callback = get_callable(self._callback_str)
File "/home/manish/syserp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/lru_cache.py" in wrapper
  101.                     result = user_function(*args, **kwds)
File "/home/manish/syserp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in get_callable
  106.         mod = import_module(mod_name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py" in import_module
  37.     __import__(name)

Exception Type: ImportError at /
Exception Value: No module named views
```

Please point out errors as this is my first django project.

Comment: You haven't told us what the error is.

Comment: please check i have edited my question

Comment: So, you have a traceback. Why didn't you post it?

Comment: also django version would be nice ... at first glance try to replace `return HttpResponse(oid_list)` with `return HttpResponse(''.join(oid_list))`

Comment: In your urls.py, try changing the string `'views.pack'` to the callable `views.pack`, like your other url patterns.

Comment: django is version 1.8.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the form's html code, simply set the action attribute to action='/test/'.

Again in views.py

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    list_of_ids = request.POST.getlist('no')
    for id in list_of_ids:
        oid_list.append(id)
```

try this, it should help

Comment: i did and it worked. But when i select all checkbox and press button it doesn't display the ids.

Comment: Now it says page not found. `Request Method: POST` and `Request URL: http://localhost:8000/test/`.   Using the URLconf defined in chkbx.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    ^admin/
    ^$

The current URL, test/, didn't match any of these

Comment: I removed the above error but it just display the same page. and not showing list of ids.